# In spring-batch, how can I get the exception when there is a chunk error?

Tags: spring-batch

Spring batch provides a listener for capturing when a chunk error has occurred (either the @AfterChunkError annotation or the ChunkListener.afterChunkError interface). Both receive the ChunkContext and the API says:

> **Parameters**:
>
> `context` - the chunk context containing the exception that caused the
>   underlying rollback.

However, I don't see anything on the ChunkContext interface that would get me to the exception. How do I get from the ChunkContext to the relevant exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exception is located in `ChunkListener.ROLLBACK_EXCEPTION_KEY` attribute:

```
context.getAttribute(ChunkListener.ROLLBACK_EXCEPTION_KEY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing a `ChunkListener` you could implement one or more of [`ItemReadListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemReadListener.html), [`ItemProcessListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemProcessListener.html) and [`ItemWriteListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html) (or more simply [`ItemListenerSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ItemListenerSupport.html)).

They respectively give acces to :

```
void onReadError(java.lang.Exception ex)
void onProcessError(T item, java.lang.Exception e)
void onWriteError(java.lang.Exception exception, java.util.List<? extends S> items)
```

I know this forces you to implement multiple methods to manage every aspect of a chunk, but you can write a custom method which takes an `Exception` and call it from these 3 methods.